# C# Event: definition: how can be NULL?

Tags: c#, event-handling, undefined

in a C# tutorial about usage of MVVM with Xamarin.Forms I stumbled upon the following sequence inside a MVVM class:

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName) {
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
```

The author suggests that one does a null check on PropertyChanged, bevore invoking it:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
```

Under which circumstances can PropertyChanged be null? I mean, it's not only declared a line above, not declaring it won't let the code compile, so how could PropertyChanged ever be null?

Comment: Declaring it doesn't mean assigning it. The null check is a general guideline, for all events (delegates).

Comment: It's null in your own example! Did you try it? I suspect not.

Comment: As @DourHighArch says you already have [MCVE] in your post... Can you please clarify why do you believe the code in the post does not show "Under which circumstances can PropertyChanged be null"?

Comment: @Dour & Alexei: I tried before asking, and it worked with and without he check, believe me. The code is piece of a Xamarin Forms project. Sorry, I didn't mention this because I didn't think it was relevant. As far as I know now, in a Xamarin.Forms project this event is always subscribed to by the Xamarin.Forms library, so within the Xamarin ecosystem it is never null. Nevertheless it is good practice to check. I'll change my question text accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally *other classes* register theire handler on your class that declared the `public event whatever` - as long as no class has registered its handler on your `PropertyChanged` named event handler, it is in fact `null`.

Therefore it is recommended to use

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)
```

to avoid getting a NullRef Exception.

Documentation on MSDN: [PropertyChangedEventHandler Delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx)

Readup event handling: [Handling and Raising Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/index)

---

Code/Usage:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel; 

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        C1 c1 = new C1();  // create instance of class that raises event 
        L1 l1 = new L1();  // create instance of 1st class that handles event
        L2 l2 = new L2();  // create instande of 2nd class that handles event

        // no handlers are yet registered on the event

        try
        {
            c1.Raise(); // will crash and output exception as no handler set yet
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        c1.SafeRaise(); // safe, will print message

        l1.AddListener(c1); // add as listener 
        c1.Raise();         // prints handled message

        l2.AddListener(c1); // add 2nd listener
        c1.Raise();         // both print handled message

        Console.ReadLine(); // stop console from closing
    }

    // Has the prop-changed and 2 raise-methods, 1 safe, 1 not.
    public class C1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // unsafe - will throw if not yet any listerer registered
        public void Raise() => 
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                DateTime.Now.ToString()));

        // safe, even if no listener registered.
        public void SafeRaise()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(
                DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            Console.WriteLine("PropertyHandlerNotSet! - but safe due to '"+
                              " PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChanged"+
                              "EventArgs(DateTime.Now.ToString()));' ");
        }
    }

    public class L1
    {
        public void AddListener(C1 c) => c.PropertyChanged += this.Handler;

        public void Handler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
            => Console.WriteLine("L1: " + e.PropertyName);
    }

    public class L2
    {
        public void AddListener(C1 c) => c.PropertyChanged += this.Handler;

        public void Handler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
            => Console.WriteLine("L2: " + e.PropertyName);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.
PropertyHandlerNotSet! - but safe due to ' PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new Pro
pertyChangedEventArgs(DateTime.Now.ToString()));'
L1: 06.03.2018 23:03:50                   // 1st raise after registering
L1: 06.03.2018 23:03:50                   // 2nd raise after registering
L2: 06.03.2018 23:03:50
```

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. My view on how event handlers are declared and called has just turned 180 degrees :-) To be sure whether I really got it:... if this code is linked with the Xamarin.Forms library, which has a handler for the PropertyChangedEventHandler event, then PropertyChanged gets a non-null value? if so - what if more than one library had a PropertyChangedEventHandler? Would the compiler reject this, or would all handlers try to get active?

Comment: @Nimral - see code.

Comment: @Nimral I dont know about Xamarin, mostly doing WPF this days. You can register multiple handlers and all get notified "simultaneously" in an unordered fashion. All can handle the raised Event as they see fit.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the full scope. However, here are a couple of possibilities:

**It is exposed as public**

`PropertyChanged` is marked as `public`, which means that an outside actor could set it to some other value, including null. Even if the member were private, an internal method could still fail to set the value.

**It is not assigned**

In the snippet, you don't indicate if the variable is ever assigned a value. If executed as shown, it will be null.

Comment: The snippet ist from a Xamarin.Forms project. Once declared, the event can be called by my own code, and does inform Xamarin.Forms that a bound member has changed value. Xamarin will then update the value on screen. I hadn't looked into event handlers too deep yet, now as I have read the basics about "delegate model" and "observer pattern" things fall into place.